# Swift- Setting uitextview text compress the text size

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

In iOS 8 on iPad device, i tried to set UITextView text in Code file. It just compresses the text size. Event i have tried this one.

myTextView.text = myTextView.text

It also compressed the text size. I don't know why UITextview is behaving like this in iOS 8

OR is this because XCode-6 is of Beta version and may have bugs?

Comment: What do you mean "compress" the text size? What is the font size you are setting as? Have you tried `sizeToFit`?

Comment: "compresss" means, it made font size very low. Yes, i have tried the sizeToFit. But nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OMG! I can't believe it. I've disabled the UITextView's Selectable propery in Interface Builder. When i enabled it again. It just resolved the issue.

Although, i have resolved the issue, but it has left a question for me. Is this Apple's issue or of something else?